Automation scanning the docs in mobile
I’m working on the project where user will have to scan the passport , VISA & other documents  and need upload in to app via IOS, Android and desktop.
I wanted to automate E2E test using Appium , is there any way we can automate scanning functionality? Can we ingest documents using API call? Please explain if there is any best approach to automate test.
I’m looking for best solution to above.
